# How to find inverse of convolution integral?

Tags: convolution, homework, inverse-problem

If $x^{-1}(t)$ and $ y^{-1}(t)$ denote the integrals of x(t) and y(t)  defined by

$x^{-1}(t)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\lambda)d\lambda$

$y^{-1}(t)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{t}y(\lambda)d\lambda$

then,

$(x*y)^{-1}$ which denotes the inverse integral of (x*y )is equal to:

(a) $x^{-1}*y^{-1}$

(b) $x*y$

(c)$x^{-1}*y$

(d)$x*y^{-1}$

i tried it follows:

from both conditions above we can easily infer following

$\dfrac{d}{dt}x^{-1}(t)=x(t)\implies sX^{-1}(s)=X(s)$

$\dfrac{d}{dt}y^{-1}(t)=y(t)\implies sY^{-1}(s)=Y(s)$

then i multiplied both(keeping in mind multiplication in freq. domain corresponds to convolution in time domain)

$s^2[X^{-1}(s)Y^{-1}(s)]=X(s).Y(s)$

$s[X^{-1}(s)Y^{-1}(s)]=\dfrac{X(s).Y(s)}{s}$

$[sX^{-1}(s)Y^{-1}(s)]=\dfrac{X(s).Y(s)}{s}$

$[X(s)Y^{-1}(s)]=\dfrac{X(s).Y(s)}{s}] \implies x*y^{-1}=(x*y)^{-1}$

and also,

if i would've written as

$s[X^{-1}(s)Y^{-1}(s)]=\dfrac{X(s).Y(s)}{s}$

$[X^{-1}(s)sY^{-1}(s)]=\dfrac{X(s).Y(s)}{s}$

$[X^{-1}(s)Y(s)]=\dfrac{X(s).Y(s)}{s}\implies x^{-1}*y=(x*y)^{-1}$

so, options (c,d) both should be correct but in the book the answer is given as

only option (c)

so , where i am doing mistake, and what should be the correct answer, i'm stuck

with this book's faulty answers...so,please help

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. Normally I would interpret $x^{-1}$ as $1/x$. And you also mention "inverse integral", what is that? But more importantly, you define $x^{-1}(t)$ as the integral over the real line, so the result is *constant*, and not a function of $t$. This is probably not what you mean.

Comment: @ Matt L ....nothing is specially mentioned about 'inverse' in the question i've written question as it is given in the book........i took 'inverse' .meaning .....'as integrator' due to division by 's(jw)'

Comment: After the two first formulas you write "... which denotes the *inverse integral* ...". And the title of you question is "inverse convolution integral". And still, your first two integrals are just *numbers*, not functions of $t$. I think you're missing a $t$ as upper integration limit, don't you?

Comment: @Matt L....... in book upper limit is 'infinity'  but should be 't'(by definition of integrator in time domain) ....you're right ....now what should be done ahead

Comment: @ Matt L .....(x * y) denotes convolution so, i thought (x*y)^{-1}  would denote 'inverse' of convolution as per definition of 'inverse' for this specific question........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of a signal $x(t)$

$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)d\tau$$

can be written as the convolution of $x(t)$ with the unit step function $u(t)$:

$$f(t)=(x\star u)(t)$$

Consequently, the integral of a convolution

$$g(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t(x\star y)(\tau)d\tau$$

can be written as

$$g(t)=((x\star y)\star u)(t)$$

And due to associativity of convolution we have

$$g(t)=((x\star u)\star y)(t)=((y\star u)\star x)(t)$$

So options $(c)$ and $(d)$ in your question are both correct.

Comment: @ Matt L.......thank you so much......you always exploit basic properties of convolution(mostly assosciativity) . ....your solutions are always nice.....